# Are there mistakes in calculus of $xy'+(x+1)y = 3x^2e^{-x}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given equation:

$$xy'+(x+1)y = 3x^2e^{-x}$$

I am fond of Lagrange's method, therefore:

$$xy'+(x+1)y = 0$$

$$xy' = -(x+1)y$$

$$\frac{xdy}{dx} = -(x+1)y$$

$$xdy = -(x+1)ydx$$

$$-\int \frac{dy}{y} = \int \frac{(x+1)\, dx}{x}$$

Solving separately:

$$\int \frac{(x+1)\, dx}{x} = \begin{array}{|c|}  x + 1 = t \\ x = t - 1 \\ dt =dx \end{array} = \int\frac{tdt}{t - 1} = \int \frac{t-1+1 \, dt}{t-1} = \int dt + \int \frac{dt}{t-1} = (t+\ln|t-1|) + C$$

And therefore $\ln|y| = -((x+1)+\ln x)+C$ or $y = Ce^{(-x-1)-\ln x}$

---

Make it $x$ dependent:

$$\begin{align}y(x) &= \frac{C(x) \cdot e^{(-x-1)}}{x}&\\ =& \frac{[C'(x)\cdot e^{(-x-1)} - C(x)\cdot e^{(-x-1)}]\cdot x+C(x) \cdot e^{(-x-1)}}{x^2} &\\=& \frac{[C'(x)\cdot e^{(-x-1)} - C(x)\cdot e^{(-x-1)}]\cdot x}{x^2} + \frac{C(x) \cdot e^{(-x-1)}}{x^2}\end{align}$$

I am actually stuck here, after substituting to original equation I did not get things reduced, are there any mistakes? (Sorry if calculus seems to be long)

Comment: No substitution is needed to evaluate $$\int \frac{x-1}{x}dx$$

Because:

$$\int \frac{x+1}{x}dx = \int (1 + 1/x)dx = x + \ln|x| + C $$

Comment: You can simplify by taking $-1$ inside $C$ to get $\ln y   = -x + -\ln x+ C$.

Comment: @Math_QED, oops, I overthinked the integral, but I am still confused if I am wrong with derivative then

Answer (score 1):

You should perhaps first simplify the constants to then consider $$u(x)=xe^xy(x)$$ with $$u'(x)=e^x(xy'+(x+1)y).$$

Answer (score 0):

The homogemeous solution is $$-\ln y = \ln x + x + C $$

or $y = cx^{-1}e^{-x}$, so we guess a particular solution of the form

$$ y(x) = C(x)x^{-1}e^{-x} $$

Plugging in gives
$$ \begin{align} y' &= C'x^{-1}e^{-x} + C(-x^{-1}-x^{-2})e^{-x} \\&= C'x^{-1}e^{-x} - Cx^{-2}(x+1)e^{-x} \end{align} $$

$$ \begin{align} xy' + (x+1)y &= C'e^{-x} - Cx^{-1}(x+1)e^{-x} + (x+1)Cx^{-1}e^{-x} \\ &= C'e^{-x} \end{align} $$

Thus
$$ C'e^{-x} = 3x^2e^{-x} $$
$$ C' = 3x^2 $$
$$ C = x^3 $$

So the general solution is
$$ y(x) = (x^2+cx^{-1})e^{-x} $$